# renaming multiple files adding a counter in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I had a look around other topics, but I am still doing it wrong. I am  a total beginner in bash, sorry if I'm asking something already asked in other topics.
My purpose: change the name of multiple files adding numbers to them. E.g.:
my files: filexx.txt, fileyy.txt, filezz.txt
The result I want:
test_name_1_filexx.txt, test_name_2_fileyy.txt, test_name_3_filezz.txt

What I have written so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=1
MYSTRING=test_name_
for i in *.txt
do
 mv "$i" "$(printf $MYSTRING $COUNTER '_' $i)"
 COUNTER="$COUNTER"+1
done
```

The above basically leaves only the last file in the directory, and it names it "test_name_"  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
$ printf foo bar baz
foo
```

The "bar" and "baz" are ignored. This is because `printf` takes one message with format specifiers, and a number of variables to substitute:

```
$ printf "%s, %s and %s" foo bar baz
foo, bar and baz
```

Since it looks like you just want to concatenate variables, there's no point in using `printf` at all:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
mystring=test_name_
for i in *.txt
do
 mv "$i" "${mystring}${counter}_${i}"
 counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash:

```
MYSTRING="test_name_"
c=1; for i in *.txt; do echo mv -v "$i" "${MYSTRING}$((c++))_$i"; done
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.